# Azure devops pipeline only publishes web projects

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-task

The following YAML produced only web projects, my repo has 2 web api projects, 1 blazor and one regular asp.net core but only the asp.net core and blazor get published to 'drop' and the web api projects are ignored.
path of my .sln and files

> \front-ends\webproject\webproject.csproj  - regular razor project,
> this gets added to the drop as webproject.zip
>
> \front-ends\blazorproject\blazorproject.csproj  - blazor project, this
> gets added to the drop as blazorproject.zip
>
> \services\api1\api.csproj  - not showing in the drop
>
> \services\api2\api2.csproj  - not showing in the drop

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2 
  displayName: ".NET Core 6"
  inputs:
    version: '6.0.x'
    packageType: sdk


- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: 'f5775ae3-da0e-4b38-82f0-ce288b91309b'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "Publish"
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    arguments: '-r win-x64 --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `publishWebProjects: false` to the `task: DotNetCoreCLI@2 (publish) as the [default value is true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#yaml-snippet)